# HTML page do not scroll on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, overflow

while creting a layout for my project I encountered a major problem. I cannot force web page to scroll on mobile devices. You can check out how the page behaves here : https://abeedesk.com/beta

That's the css I've got. Also I tried to force overflow bo changing it via the JS window.onload, which have not helped.

Thanks you your time!

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 512px) {
  body {
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    max-height: 100vh;
    overflow: scroll;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

remove max-height:100vh

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 512px) {
  body {
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
height: auto;
overflow: scroll;
```

}
}

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not it

Answer (score 0):

Your Js file "scripts.432fe7153128e7650472.js" is the reason behind scroll not working on mobile devices.
I disable "scripts.432fe7153128e7650472.js" in the browser using network property after scroll working on a mobile device properly.

Comment: Yeah, that's true but then aplication does not work.